# Filtering data after GROUP BY() or vice versa?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below are the tables in MySQL

```
Table:ShopInfo

ShopCode     ShopName
--------     -------
X            Xylophon
Y            Yellow
Z            Zoota
K            Kite

Table: Income

Shop     Date           Earnings
-----    ----------     --------
X        2014-10-17     4000
Y        NULL           NULL
Y        2014-11-09     5000
Y        2014-11-18     3000
Y        2014-12-05     2000
Z        2014-12-25     6000
K        NULL           NULL
```

I want to find the **Total Earning for each Shop in the month of November only**, Null earning will be replaced with zero. The result table will be

```
ShopName    NovEarn
--------    -------
Yellow      8000
Kite        0
```

This is What I am doing:

```
SELECT ShopInfo.ShopName, IFNULL( SUM(Income.Earnings), 0 ) AS NovEarn
FROM Income
JOIN ShopInfo ON Income.Shop=ShopName.ShopCode
GROUP BY Income.Shop
HAVING (MONTH(Income.Date)=11 AND YEAR(Income.Date)=2014) OR Date IS NULL
ORDER BY NovEarn DESC
```

And its giving me

```
ShopName    NovEarn
--------    -------
Yellow      10000
Kite        0
```

That is, the sum of earnings for all the months. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the having clauses under where clauses :

```
SELECT ShopInfo.ShopName, IFNULL( SUM(Income.Earnings), 0 ) AS NovEarn
FROM Income
JOIN ShopInfo ON Income.Shop=ShopName.ShopCode
WHERE (MONTH(Income.Date)=11 AND YEAR(Income.Date)=2014) OR Date IS NULL
GROUP BY Income.Shop
ORDER BY NovEarn DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering income by month has to be done BEFORE you group by show code. Use a where statement for that part. But then you will have the problem of keeping shops with no income. So you should select first from ShopInfo, and then left join on income, so that if there are no acceptable income, the shop will still be displayed.

```
SELECT ShopInfo.ShopName, IFNULL( SUM(Income.Earnings), 0 ) AS NovEarn
FROM ShopInfo
LEFT JOIN Income ON ShopName.ShopCode = Income.Shop
WHERE (MONTH(Income.Date)=11 AND YEAR(Income.Date)=2014)
GROUP BY ShopInfo.ShopCode
ORDER BY NovEarn DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a `HAVING` condition on column `Income.Date` which you don't group by.

You should put date conditions to `WHERE` clause.

Something like:

```
SELECT ShopInfo.ShopName, IFNULL( SUM(Income.Earnings), 0 ) AS NovEarn
FROM Income
JOIN ShopInfo ON Income.Shop=ShopName.ShopCode
WHERE (MONTH(Income.Date)=11 AND YEAR(Income.Date)=2014)
GROUP BY Income.Shop
ORDER BY NovEarn DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ShopInfo.ShopName, SUM(COALESCE(Income.Earnings,0)) AS NovEarn
FROM Income
JOIN ShopInfo ON Income.Shop=ShopName.ShopCode
WHERE (MONTH(Income.Date)=11 AND YEAR(Income.Date)=2014) OR Date IS NULL
GROUP BY Income.Shop
ORDER BY NovEarn DESC
```